# If $Df(c)=0$ $\forall c\in V$ then $f$ is constant on $V$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

**Theorem:**

Suppose that $V$ is open and connected in $\Bbb R^n$

$f:V\to \Bbb R^m$ is differentiable on $V$

If $Df(c)=0$ $\forall c\in V$ then $f$ is constant on $V$

---

I want to prove this theorem with mean value theorem for real valued functions.

How to prove this?

---

Comment: You can use the multivariable mean value theorem.

Comment: No. My instructor want to use MVT for real valued functions. Please can you show me the proof? @Potato

Comment: @Sharkos I saw thissolution now. But he solved it by using MVT FOR VECTOR VALUED FUNCTIONS. but I want to use MVT for REAL VALUED FUNCTİONS. :(

Comment: @B11b Well I didn't... Restrict to a line between points, done.

Comment: @B11b Hand on, real **valued**  functions? That's a completely trivial distinction, work componentwise and it's the same.

Answer (score 2):

If $a\not=b$, the line passing through $a$ and $b$ must contain a point $c$ where the derivative of the restriction $g$ of $f$ to that line parametrised by length along that line is $g'(c)=\frac{g(a)-g(c)}{a-b}$. If $D(f)=0$ everywhere, then $\displaystyle g'(c)$ is always $0$.

For any point $c$ in an open set, points $a$ and $b$ can be chosen in an arbitrarily small neighbourhood of  $c$ with the line between then passing through $c$, and since differentiable functions must be continuous, $g(a)=g(b)$ and hence $f(a)=f(b)$ everywhere in $V$.